# Any languages that don't have consecutive letters?

Tags: orthography, list-of-languages

I was wondering if anyone knew of a language (real or fictional!) that did not contain any double consecutive letters (like the double t in "letters").

Thanks!

Comment: Mandarin in pinyin.

Comment: @user6726 what about intra-word, incidental repetition between final and initial, as in *Zhōn**gg**uó* or *bà**nn**ián*?

Comment: Ok, point taken.

Comment: Does it matter whether two consecutive letters represent two phonemes (or a long phoneme), or is this strictly about spelling? If it's about English spelling, it's off topic here.

Comment: @jlawler, this is about spelling - but not English spelling, because clearly that does have double letter combinations. I think it's on topic based on other questions I have seen here (orthography is not strictly a subset of linguistics but it is related)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: My guess is that if you actually run a check over a real corpus, there will always be some, because of Roman numerals and loan words or named entities or abbreviations.

Comment: From European languages, Serbian comes to mind.  In theory if there were a word ending with -ia then -ii would occur, in practice everything is written with -ija.  But again, I would not be surprised if there are some exceptions.

Comment: The OP should clarify whether the space between words counts as a break.  The function of doubled letters is mainly to extend the vowels.  Norse runes are pretty good at sticking to their base orthography.

Comment: I thought Spanish didn't allow double letters, and that _ll_ and _rr_ were regarded as distinct (single) letters in Spanish orthography; but it appears I am out of date.

Comment: Dutch has no consonant geminates in pronunciation but does write words with double consonants to mark quality/length (latten vs laten e.g. ; there's one [t] in both.) And words like na-apen have a glottal stop between the vowels. (In other cases there can be semivowels/glides between (almost) identical vowel sounds).

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: "[Serbian: An Essential Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=ESwmuYj84LoC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=double+j)", by Lila Hammond, gives "najjači" as an exception to the general absence of double letter sequences in Serbian orthography.

Comment: Right, there are some compounds, like *tamnooker*, and the superlative (formed with *naj+*) of any adjective that starts with *j*, so *najjači* from *jako*, *najjeftiniji* from *jeftino*...

Comment: @ColinFine In Spanish there are cases like *cc* in *construcción*.

Comment: @ColinFine IIRC ll & rr were considered distinct separate letters (and alphabetised accordingly) but are now considered repetitions of the letters l & r respectively. I know Welsh does consider its ll its own letter though, and I think phonotactics prohibit clusters of digraphs that would result in repeated letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.

Many languages don't allow consonants at the ends of syllables, which means that two of the same consonant will never be next to each other by chance.

Of these languages, some have long/geminate vowels/consonants, or the same vowel twice in a row, and write that with double letters (e.g. Japanese written in Roumaji). So those are no good.

Others either write their geminates differently, like Māori (Polynesian, uses macrons), or don't have length contrasts, like Lingála (Bantu). So those will work for you.

EDIT: Māori may actually have double vowels sometimes! See the comments for details. The point about Lingála stands.

Comment: Languages that don't have coda consonants might still have heterosyllabic sequences of the same vowel. I don't know Maori, but it seems to have words written with "aa" like "whakaaraara".

Comment: @sumelic There's some disagreement still about the orthography, but the most official one (used by the local government) spells that "whakārāra" with macrons instead of double vowels. (Or "whakärära" if you're stuck with pre-Unicode codepages, which are still unfortunately common.)

Comment: @sumelic (That said, added a note about vowel sequences)

Comment: I guess that page also seems to say that "whak**aa**ko" has a long vowel, so maybe /aa/ coalesces to /a:/ in Maori? I found a paper that says "In Maori, sequences of double vowels may be realized for the same word as a double
articulated vowel, a long vowel, or two vowels separated by a glottal stop." ([The Phonetic Nature of Niuean
Vowel Length](http://www.ensani.ir/storage/Files/20101124161924-29.pdf), Nicholas Roll, p. 16)

Comment: I just looked at the "[Guidelines for
Mäori Language Orthography](http://www.tetaurawhiri.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/translators-docs/Guidelines-for-Maori-Language-Orthography.pdf)", and it says "In words made up of distinct word-parts or ‘morphemes’ [...] , if the last vowel of the first word-part is short, and that vowel is also the first letter of the second word-part, the two vowels are written separately in place of a macronised single vowel [...] Addition of prefix:
whaka- + aro > whakaaro ‘to think’ (not whakāro, whakaro)" (p. 5). So I think "aa" is part of the official spelling system.

Comment: @sumelic Interesting! I didn't know that; I'll edit the answer

Comment: Lingala seems to have at least one word written with two of the same vowel letters in sequence: "[ee](https://dic.lingala.be/)", meaning "yes".

Comment: Japanese syllable can actually end with an *-n*, creating double consonant in Romaji spelling, like in the greeting *Kon-ni-chi-wa*

Comment: @MiloBem Indeed; Japanese can also have other geminate consonants and long vowels, which are also often written double in Roumaji.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's distinguish between double letters that function as digraphs indicating a single sound (like English "oo" in "flood", which corresponds to the single vowel phoneme /ʌ/, or "dd" in "middle", which corresponds to the single consonant phoneme /d/), and double letters that arise from the incidental repetition of the same sound without any intervening sounds.

There are many languages with writing systems that don't make use of double consonant letters as digraphs. And as Draconis pointed out, many languages don't allow consonants at the ends of syllables, which would prevent double consonant letters from arising incidentally.

But it's harder to figure out whether a language can never have consecutive vowel letters. Double vowel letter digraphs are fairly common as symbols for long vowels. And aside from that, many languages allow vowel-initial syllables, which brings up the possibility of double vowel letters arising incidentally from a sequence of the same vowel in adjacent syllables. (Languages that forbid that kind of situation often resolve the illegal vowel sequence by turning it into a long vowel, which as mentioned might be written with a double vowel digraph.)

If you include sequences of letters separated by a space, that would cause further difficulties, because languages often either don't have or don't write sound changes that eliminate vowel-vowel sequences across word-space boundaries.

If you don't include sequences of letters separated by a space, I think [Vietnamese](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/vietnamese-word-space-spacing.3067954/) might qualify, because of the general practice of writing a space between all of the syllables in a Vietnamese sentence, regardless of word grouping. In the linked Wordreference thread, the original poster asked if mặttrời would be an acceptable spelling of mặt trời, and was told to use the spaced spelling.

As far as I can make out from the [Wikipedia article on Vietnamese spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_alphabet), a doubled letter shouldn't be possible in a single written syllable of Vietnamese. Vietnamese does have a diphthong written "ưu", which might look like a double letter to an English speaker, but ư and u are considered to be separate letters of the Vietnamese alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Old Church Slavonic is another language with strictly open syllables.

Exceptions might be some foreign words. The dictionary (Cejtlin, Večerka, Bláhová, 1994) has both елинъ and еллинъ (and also елиньнъ) - Greek.

Answer (score -2):

Latvian and Hebrew do not allow double consonants. Even when mentioning names of people from other languages they will drop the second consonant. Thus Wasserman becomes Waserman in both languages. Any other languages with this property?

Comment: As for Hebrew there are words like הללויה. But your point about Latvian might still stand. I don't know enough Latvian to say.

Comment: The claim on Latvian is wrong. Skimming a random page on the Latvian Wikipedia I encountered the word [sauss](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sauss) with double s at the end.

Comment: Another nice Lativan word with a double consonant in the middle: *galvassāpes* "headache".